# invalid Date.parse while converting CSV dates, i tried Date.strptime too

Tags: ruby, csv

I am finding it nearly impossible to parse these dates

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'
CSV.foreach(path, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
  bid_date = Date.parse(row[7])
end
```

the error i get says `'parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)`

I have also given Date.strptime a try as well, i get `'strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)`

I have no issues converting my own strings to dates, but when they are coming out of this CSV file I cant seem to get it to work, any thoughts?

if i dont parse it returns the strings as follows:
02/25/2016
03/03/2016
03/04/2016
03/14/2016
03/17/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your input dates (e.g. `02/25/2016`) can't be parsed as is by `Date.parse` - you can use `strptime` to provide the format, e.g.

`Date.strptime('02/25/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')`

So you would want something like:

```
CSV.foreach(path, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
  bid_date = Date.strptime(row[7], '%m/%d/%Y')
end
```